# I have to click my burger bar navigation twice to trigger the event listener

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry for this basic question but I am new to JS. I am attempting to create a burger bar navigation menu. It work, but... when the page loads I must click the nav button twice before it will trigger. I cant work out how to stop this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

```js
const burgerBarButton = document.getElementById("burgerNavigationButton");
console.log(burgerBarButton + "initilised");
const navigationMenu = document.getElementById("mainNavID");
console.log(navigationMenu + "initilised");

burgerBarButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
"use strict";
console.log('click outside of IF');
if(navigationMenu.style.display === "none"){
    navigationMenu.style.display = "block";
    console.log('click inside of IF');
}else{
    navigationMenu.style.display = "none";
}
});
```

```html
<img class="" id="burgerNavigationButton" src="Images/burgerMenu/BurgerMenu---25x25.png" alt="Navigation Button"/>

<nav id="mainNavID" class="mainNav">
    <ul>
        <li id="homeNavigationLink"><div class="liDiv">Home</div></li>
        <li id="newsNavigationLink"><div class="liDiv">News</div></li>
        <li id="reviewsNavigationLink"><div class="liDiv">Reviews</div></li>
        <li id="techbyteNavigationLink"><div class="liDiv">TechByte</div></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: `display` should be `none` initially, most likely its `hidden` not `none`. So the first click sets it to none the second click works as expected.

Comment: Your code works for me. On a sidenote it is more common to do this kind of thing with a class like `.is-opened` on your image.

Comment: Yes. It works for me either. https://jsfiddle.net/8hqu7njL/

Answer (score 0):

I would assign a class instead of comparing the display property. If you use the display property you could run into trouble if someone decided to style your nav as e.g. `display: flex`. So try to keep styling out of your JS and in your CSS.

You could do something like this:

```js
const burgerBarButton = document.getElementById("burgerNavigationButton");

burgerBarButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let mainMenu = document.getElementById("mainNavID");
  mainMenu.classList.toggle('closed');
});
```

```css
#mainNavID.closed{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img class="" id="burgerNavigationButton" src="Images/burgerMenu/BurgerMenu---25x25.png" alt="Navigation Button"/>

<nav id="mainNavID" class="mainNav">
    <ul>
        <li id="homeNavigationLink"><div class="liDiv">Home</div></li>
        <li id="newsNavigationLink"><div class="liDiv">News</div></li>
        <li id="reviewsNavigationLink"><div class="liDiv">Reviews</div></li>
        <li id="techbyteNavigationLink"><div class="liDiv">TechByte</div></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```